# Will the probability decrease when the total number of possible outcomes increase?

Tags: probability

I have tried time and again by googling for answers, but im still not going anywhere. Since probability is obtained by dividing the number of favoured outcomes over the total amount of possibilities, will it decrease if the latter increases? EXP: There are 4 stalls in total. The probability that a visitor would be captivated to a specific stall is 1/4. But if the total number of stalls are heightened to 4+2=6,then wouldn't the ratio be 1/6, resulting in a smaller fraction and thus a decrease in probability? This is my theory, but i cant seem to find evidence for it.

Comment: The probability of what? Be clear

Answer (score 1):

This actually depends on, what is known as, the [probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution). However, in the simple example where the probability for each is the same, then yes, you're correct.

In general, if there are $n$ possible outcomes, and the probabilities for each are the same, then the probability is given by $1/n$.

Consider, as an example, two dice. One regular $6$-sided die and one $20$-sided die. Of course, rolling the number $3$ is more likely on the $6$-sided die (probability $1/6$) rather than the $20$-sided die (probability $1/20$).